# Unable to create app packages in Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am a new developer and I'm having some trouble with VS2013. I have my code complete and working, but when I go to create the app package it blacks out the option shown in this picture.
[image]

It is a SIlverlight App so I can use the designer. The account link to VS2013 is a Dev account.

Any help?

EDIT: FIXED

Here's the answer from when I asked this on Reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/WPDev/comments/24zobu/visual_studio_2013_cant_create_app_package/chdjtxk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/WPDev/comments/24zobu/visual_studio_2013_cant_create_app_package/chdjtxk) dies, here's what it says:

"Just hit Build than navigate to your documents --> Visual Studio 20** --> Projects --> Your Project Name --> Bin -> (Release or Debug depending on what's selected) there you should find a XAP file. Now head to dev.windowsphone.com sign in and submit the XAP file on the submit page in the dashboard."

Clarify: The .XAP file is located in your project folder, depending on where you have saved it, not necessary in Documents.